# Laravel Searchable Belongs To

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using the package searchable by nicolaslopezj https://github.com/nicolaslopezj/searchable and I'm trying to do a relation of belongs to, however I'm having a bit of trouble with it.

```
protected $searchable = [
    /**
     * Columns and their priority in search results.
     * Columns with higher values are more important.
     * Columns with equal values have equal importance.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    'columns' => [
        'products.title' => 10,
        'products.description' => 5,
    ],
    'joins' => [
        "brand" => ['products.brand_id', 'brands.id']
    ],
];

public function brand()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Brand::class);
}
```

The problem here, is that it tries to get the database table 'brand' when its called 'brands'. However if I change this to brands I get a relationship error with laravel. So I'm really unsure what to do. The documentation also doesn't explain it very well. Would love some help, thanks!

Comment: Just to clarify, changing the `"brand" => ['products.brand_id', 'brands.id']` to  `"brands" => ['products.brand_id', 'brands.id']` and changing the function `brand()` to `brands()` doesn't resolve this?

Comment: @ChewySalmon This has gotten rid of the error, however it doesn't work when I try and search for a brand. Also i'd prefer not to call it brands as its as a single element and also would break my other code.

Comment: If you're able to provide the code relating to your `$query` that you're searching, I'll attempt to solve it and edit my answer. Though I do think the answer, answers your original problem which was the relationship error, I'm happy to look!!

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your original problem as discussed with consideration of what was discussed in the comments, is to update your `Brand` model, by setting the `protected $table` variable to `'brand'` and then adjusting the above to reflect that.

This should resolve your original problem of the relationship error and keep your code consistent as you've mentioned in the comments.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Brand extends Model
{
    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'brand';
}
```

By default, Laravel will always assume that the database table is the plural form of the model name. And so, if you model is singular, you should assume it expects the database table to be the plural form unless explicitly set as above!

Adjusting your other code as follows, to reference the `brand.id` rather than `brands.id`:

```
protected $searchable = [
    /**
     * Columns and their priority in search results.
     * Columns with higher values are more important.
     * Columns with equal values have equal importance.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    'columns' => [
        'products.title' => 10,
        'products.description' => 5,
    ],
    'joins' => [
        "brand" => ['products.brand_id', 'brand.id']
    ],
];

public function brand()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Brand::class);
}
```